# ListView is giving an error displaying the files in a directory

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Here's my code:

```
package com.test.testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PreviousTrip extends Fragment {
    int i;
    String k = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        final RelativeLayout mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false );

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc/");
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder);
        lv = (ListView) mFrame3.findViewById(R.id.lvFiles);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.ptrip, FilesInFolder));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Clicking on items
             }
        });

        /*File[] filelist = folder.listFiles();
        String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        if (filelist.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
                long lastTime = filelist[i].lastModified();
                String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(lastTime)).toString();
                theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
                k = k + String.valueOf(theNamesOfFiles[i]) + " " + dateString + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

        return mFrame3;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }
}
```

My ptrip XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bginset3" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFiles"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am receiving the following error that I would help to solve:

`ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder);` **Error**: `The method GetFiles(String) in the type PreviousTrip is not applicable for the arguments (File)`
**Fixed**: `ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder.toString());`

`lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.ptrip, FilesInFolder));` **Error**: `ptrip cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Along with the above, I am trying to display each item in Card View like the "My Apps" in the Play Store like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `android.R.layout.ptrip`? It isn't a layout file in the android framework. Use `R.layout.ptrip` instead. **Edit:** Actually, even that won't work. Let me post an answer for you.

Comment: `lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ptrip, FilesInFolder));` gives me this error: `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(PreviousTrip, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined` Is it because I am using Inflater?

Comment: clean your project then you can see the xml error

Comment: XML doesn't show any error. I posted my XML file above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder); 
Error: The method GetFiles(String) in the type PreviousTrip is not applicable for the arguments (File) 
Fixed: ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder.toString());
```

I would suggest that you use `folder.getName()` rather than `folder.toString()`.

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.ptrip, FilesInFolder)); 
Error: ptrip cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

First, using `android.R.layout.some_layout` can only be possible if `some_layout` is part of android framework.

If `R.layout.ptrip` is one of your layouts, then you must provide the `id` of a `TextView` inside this layout to the constructor. For example, your initialization should look like:

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ptrip,
                               R.id.some_textview_inside_layout_ptrip, FilesInFolder));
```

If you only had a TextView in the layout file `ptrip`, then the following would not have caused an error:

```
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ptrip, FilesInFolder));
```

Comment: But shudn't Listview already show the texts? So inside my <RelativeLayout><ListView><TextView></TextView></ListView></RelativeLayout>?

Comment: So, you tried `lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));` and it didn't work?

Comment: I get this error: `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(PreviousTrip, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined` if I add `simple_list_item_1`

Comment: Your `ptrip.xml` does not have a `TextView`. Create an xml file with no layouts, button etc: only a `TextView`. And use this file as `lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textview_only_layout, FilesInFolder));`.

Comment: You need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this` because you are using a fragment.

Comment: Now i get an error for this line: `ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder.getName());` my app FC with the following Log: `NPE`

Comment: Can you post the `GetFiles(String)` method? Also, let's move this to chat: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34781/discussion-between-sikni8-and-vikram)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes.

Your are using wrong layout `ptrip` for list view items. Item layout must have a `TextView` with `android:id = "@android:id/text1"` to work automatically with `ArrayAdapter`.

Here's somewhat improved code:

```
public class PreviousTrip extends Fragment {
    int i;
    String k = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        final RelativeLayout mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false );
        final ListView lv = (ListView) mFrame3.findViewById(R.id.lvFiles);

        final File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tc");

        final ArrayList<String> files = GetFiles(directory);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,files);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Clicking on items
            }
        });

        return mFrame3;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(File directory) {
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

        directory.mkdirs();

        if(!directory.exists()){return files;}

        File[] fileArray = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++){
            files.add(fileArray[i].getName());
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did upvote your answer so you get credit because you took the time. Thanks :)